# how to erase impossible variant from enum?

Tags: rust, types, type-conversion

The setting: In a web server, the business code needs to access the request payload, which is located in either query or body, but not both, the deserialization of query is handled by a trait `Q`, and the deserialization of the body is handled by the trait `B != Q`, a middleware, `f`, (a piece of code that sitting between the web framework and business code) is responsible for the invocation of Q and B according to the request method, if it is a GET, then invoke Q, if it is a POST then invoke B, thus the signature of f must be like `f<Query: Q, Body: B>(...) -> Payload<Query, Body>`, "must be" because somewhere in the implementation of `f`:

```
let payload = if request_method == "GET" {
    let query: Query = ...::deserialize(request_query);
    Payload::Query(query)
} else if request_method == "POST" {
    let body: Body = ...::deserialize(request_body);
    Payload::Body(body)
} else {
    // error
}

...

payload
```

(sadly, I didn't find a way to tell the framework to call `f<Q>` or `f<B>`, nor a way to unify Q and B into a single trait)

In the business code, the handler for a GET would have the signature `handler(Payload<Query, ()>) ...` and a POST would have `handler(Payload<(), Body>)`

The question: is there some technique to erase the unit type from the payload without turning it into a trait (trait is difficult to work with)? (The real rationale for erasing the unit type is actually something else, but let's just say I want the unit type erased)

Edit: the meaning of "erasing" is to turn `Payload<Query, Body>` to `Query` or `Body`, i.e. `handler(Payoad<(), Body>)` would become `handler(Body)` - the "useless" unit variant of Payload<_, _> erased, resulting a enum with only one variant, essentially the "inner" itself.

Comment: When you say “erase”, what exactly do you mean? To me, we speak of “erasing” a type _parameter_ to make a single concrete type out of a generic one (usually via `dyn`), but `()` is a concrete type, not a type parameter, so I'm not sure what it would mean to erase it. Do you mean you want to end up with signatures in terms of `Payload<Query>` and `Payload<Body>` — one type parameter instead of two? Or something else? In particular, do you mean that you want the _variant_ effectively removed from the enum, like your question's title suggests? (That's doable)

Comment: @KevinReid Thanks for the comment, I've clarified the meaning of erasing in a edit, it's "end up with signatures in terms of Payload<Query> and Payload<Body>"

Comment: Perhaps this is personal opinion, but pointing the finger at how the "business logic" wants the parameter seems misguided. A function like `query_for_fish(query: FishType)` is a business logic function whereas the handling for `GET /fish?type=tuna` via some `handler(Payload<Query, Body>)` is an *adapter* function. The adapter should be concerned with taking the `Query` and deserializing it into a `FishType` to hand off to the business logic. And at no point do you have to worry about unifying `Payload<(), Body>` and `Payload<Query, ()>` types. But perhaps I'm still missing context.

Comment: Knowing more concretely what web server you're using and the exact types involved would be helpful. It sounds to me like there's better patterns available (at least in the web server frameworks I'm familiar with).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to encode in Rust's type system that a variant of an enum can never be user. You have to use empty types (also called void types). One such type (two actually, but whatever) is already present in the prelude, it's the *never* type `!`. Since it's not completely clear about where you want to use it, I'll explain with the `Result` type.

Assume you have a trait which requires returning a `Result<T, U>` where the implementer of the trait can choose which `T` and `U`. For example, `TryFrom`:

```rust
struct A;
struct B;

impl TryFrom<A> for B {
    type Error = ...;
    fn try_from(a: A) -> Result<B, Self::Error> {
        Ok(B)
    }
}
```

In this example, it's clear that this conversion cannot fail. So what should I put in place of the dots? Often people put the unit type `()` there, thinking that is carries no information (because there is a single value possible of that type) so it's perfect for the job. However, this is not exactly what we wanted, right? There *is* actually a value of the type `()`, so this doesn't *mean* it's impossible to return `Err(())`. What we want *instead* is a type of which there are no values, because in that case we are *sure* it's impossible to return a value of that type. So the correct implementation would be

```rust
impl TryFrom<A> for B {
    type Error = !;
    ...
}
```

In this case, there is even a RFC that proposes the following code to Just Work:

```rust
let Ok(b) = B::try_from(A);
```

This would be accepted, because the compiler knows it cannot be an `Err(something)`, because then `something: !` which is impossible.